# Ordnance Survey-style OSM maps

Tags: openstreetmap, ordnance-survey

1. Is there an implementation of Openstreetmap that closely mimics the appearance of 1:25k OS Explorer or 1:50k OS Landranger maps? By "mimicking the appearnace" I mean same colour scheme, same POI symbols, same typography and labeling conventions, contour lines, etc.
2. If the answer to 1. a is "no", is it possible to create such an implementation? What might be a good resource to learn how to do so?

Like many Brits, I grew up with paper OS maps and am still more comfortable reading them than a style such as that used at http://www.opentopomap.org/

Comment: Still in Beta http://geo.gy/

Comment: @Mapperz Wow, it's beautiful. Could you be persuaded to post it as an answer?

Comment: I'm sure I came across a style for Openandromaps which attempted this too. I guess though that you're searching for a map style on an internet site rather than one produced on a portable device? If you're open to wider options you're looking at a very big field of work - given that there will be individual styles developed for individual apps and individual implementations of the data on all the major platforms (Android, iOS, Windows devices, Garmin GPS, etc etc). You probably want to be asking the OSM community (help.openstreetmap.org) about this if you haven't tried yet.

Comment: @Rostranimin You're right! At least, I found this: http://gamesnight.co.uk/maps/ Thanks

Comment: @Ubiquitous - a good app (fully featured if a little comples) + good mapping. Look out other styles for Openandromaps too - the good thing about OSM and the many many styles of mapping are that one style might be more useful than another for particular uses... so learning which show you what you personally need is part of the fun. The Oruxmaps/Openandromaps system a really good way to explore this - I also grew up with OS, but it doesn't satisfy me when looking for cycling and walking paths etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently (September 2016) there is a new map service in beta status created by grough Limited in the UK. That has based OpenStreetMap Data and combined Ordnance Survey styles (as close as possible) for Hill Walking.

This website only contains Great Britain (England, Scotland and Wales.)

http://geo.gy/

[image]

Please note there are limitations like in Birmingham where the OSM data is complete and not complete (every building) they have tried to fill the gap with Ordnance Survey VectorMap District buildings (OpenData) these are not individual properties but merged units.

[image]

Buildings are patchy with the different completeness of OpenStreetMap.

It is still a very comprehensive and fine attempt of recreating the 1:25k Maps based on opendata.